# SwiftUI Form Picker Selected Background Color

Tags: swiftui

How do I get rid of the background color after I select a value in the Form Picker?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

```
Form() {
                    
    Picker(selection: self.$MonthIndex, label: Text("Month") ) {
                        
         ForEach(0 ..< self.months.count ) {
             Text("\(self.months[$0])").tag($0)
         }
                        
   }
```

I have adjusted the init() file for a few things. Is there one for the "selected" cell?

```
init(){
    
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
    UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
    UITableView.appearance().tintColor = .green
    
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
    UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = .green
   
}
```

thank you.

Comment: I was reported this appeared in latest Xcode 12 beta and looks like a bug. I don't think it requires workaround now, just submit one more feedback to Apple.

Comment: I am using Xcode 11.6.  thanks.

Comment: Not reproduced with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14 - highlight is removed on picker selection changed.

Comment: @Asperi i downloaded the new xcode and the problem persists...

Comment: Anybody got solution to this?

Comment: No solution, but can confirm I just ran into this bug in Xcode 12.3 (12C33), iOS 14. The problem shows on both the simulator and a real device. In my case I am using a picker in a `List { ... }` with `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())`